# Gitlab Trigger Pipelines Generically by Group ID

Tags: gitlab

I want to create a repo that triggers all projects under some group id on Gitlab, That is useful for infra repos that are used by many consumers, for example bumping a new helm version and then need to update 30 repos.

I have the following error:

```
The rules configuration prevented any jobs from being added to the pipeline
```

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
---
stages:
  - trigger
  
# Populators
process|populators:
  stage: trigger
  image: $TOOLBOX_IMAGE_STABLE
  variables:
    POPULATORS_GROUP_ID: "13477936"
    DATA_PIPELINES_GROUP_ID: "57325826"
  script:
    - |
      # Get the projects for POPULATORS_GROUP_ID
      POPULATORS=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_API_TOKEN}" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/${POPULATORS_GROUP_ID}/projects?include_subgroups=true" | jq -r ".[].path_with_namespace")
      
      # Get the projects for DATA_PIPELINES_GROUP_ID
      DATA_PIPELINES=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_API_TOKEN}" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/${DATA_PIPELINES_GROUP_ID}/projects?include_subgroups=true" | jq -r ".[].path_with_namespace")
      
      # Combine the two arrays into one array
      COMBINED_ARRAY=($POPULATORS $DATA_PIPELINES)      
      
      # Convert the combined array to a single-line string
      export PROJECTS=$(printf '["%s"]' "$(echo "${COMBINED_ARRAY[@]}" | sed 's/ /","/g')")
      
      # Replace PROJECTS on redeploy.yml
      envsubst '${PROJECTS}' < redeploy.yml > redeploy.gitlab-ci.yml
      cat redeploy.gitlab-ci.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - redeploy.gitlab-ci.yml

redeploy|populators:
  stage: trigger
  variables:
    NAMESPACE: "$NAMESPACE" # Prevent deploying to `common` namespace
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: redeploy.gitlab-ci.yml
        job: process|populators
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true        
  needs:
    - job: process|populators
```

`redeploy.yml`

```
---
include:
  - project: mycompany/devops/ci-cd/gitlab/auto-pipeline
    file: auto-pipeline/main.yaml
    ref: $AUTO_PIPELINE_STABLE

variables:
  GRAFANA_ANNOTATION: "false"

# Populators
process|populators:
  stage: .post
  image: $TOOLBOX_IMAGE_STABLE
  secrets:
    GITLAB_API_TOKEN:
      vault: mycompany/mygroup/myteam/populators/all/POPULATORS_GITLAB_API_TOKEN@gitlab
      file: false  
  variables:
    POPULATORS_GROUP_ID: "13477936"
    DATA_PIPELINES_GROUP_ID: "13477936" # TODO: Change to 57325826
  script:
    - |
      # Get the projects for POPULATORS_GROUP_ID
      POPULATORS=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_API_TOKEN}" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/${POPULATORS_GROUP_ID}/projects?include_subgroups=true" | jq -r ".[].path_with_namespace")
      
      # Get the projects for DATA_PIPELINES_GROUP_ID
      DATA_PIPELINES=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_API_TOKEN}" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/${DATA_PIPELINES_GROUP_ID}/projects?include_subgroups=true" | jq -r ".[].path_with_namespace")
      
      # Combine the two arrays into one array
      COMBINED_ARRAY=($POPULATORS $DATA_PIPELINES)      
      
      # Convert the combined array to a single-line string
      export PROJECTS=$(printf '["%s"]' "$(echo "${COMBINED_ARRAY[@]}" | sed 's/ /","/g')")
      
      # Replace PROJECTS on redeploy.yml
      envsubst '${PROJECTS}' < redeploy.yml > redeploy.gitlab-ci.yml
      cat redeploy.gitlab-ci.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - redeploy.gitlab-ci.yml

redeploy|populators:
  stage: .post
  variables:
    NAMESPACE: "$NAMESPACE" # Prevent deploying to `populators-bs-common` namespace
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: redeploy.gitlab-ci.yml
        job: process|populators
    forward:
      pipeline_variables: true        
  needs:
    - job: process|populators
```

Any ideas why?
Thanks! :)

---

The artifact `redeploy.gitlab-ci.yml` looks as follows:

```
stages:
  - redeploy
redeploy:
  stage: redeploy
  variables:
    NAMESPACE: "$NAMESPACE" # Prevent deploying to `populators-bs-common` namespace
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - PROJECT: ["populators/populators-bs-common","populators/page-classifications-connector-v3","populators/site-classifications-v2-connector","populators/geo-profile-settings-populator","populators/page-classifications-connector-v2","populators/client-categories-connector","populators/page-override-lists-connector","populators/page-classifications-connector","populators/site-classifications-connector","populators/site-list-items-connector","populators/profile-ids-connector","populators/aerospike-connect-myteam","populators/site-exclusion-list-items-connector","populators/profile-settings-populator","populators/populators-bs-common","populators/page-classifications-connector-v3","populators/site-classifications-v2-connector","populators/geo-profile-settings-populator","populators/page-classifications-connector-v2","populators/client-categories-connector","populators/page-override-lists-connector","populators/page-classifications-connector","populators/site-classifications-connector","populators/site-list-items-connector","populators/profile-ids-connector","populators/aerospike-connect-myteam","populators/site-exclusion-list-items-connector","populators/profile-settings-populator"]
  trigger:
    project: $PROJECT
    strategy: depend
```

[image]